# How to create table inside another table in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to create a table inside another table in Bootstrap-3. I tried but it displays after the first table.

Comment: ah .. you are still after tables in bootstrap too ??

Comment: Sorry, i cant understand your question, can you please say it clearly

Answer (score 17):

You need to do as below

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <th colspan="3">Outer Table</th>
  <tr>
    <td>This is row one, column 1</td>
    <td>This is row one, column 2</td>
    <td>
     <table class="table table-bordered">
       <th colspan="3">Inner Table</th>
       <tr>
         <td>This is row one, column 1</td>
         <td>This is row one, column 2</td>
         <td>This is row one, column 3</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/qilebevo/1/

Comment: how to remove bottom margin 20px in the inside table?

Comment: simply add `style="margin-bottom:0;"` to the inneer table i.e `<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-bottom:0;">`